# jQuery dataTables sorting is incorrect (latin letter D with stroke)

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I have a table and need to sort by one column ascending, but "Đ Garrett Winters" is after the "Tiger Nixon"

Order Correct in Column Name is "Ashton Cox","Cedric Kelly","Đ Garett Winters","Tiger Nixon" ...

[image: sotting datatable]

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/xshh5np8/55/)

```js
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "non-empty-string-asc": function (str1, str2) {
        if(str1 == "")
            return 1;
        if(str2 == "")
            return -1;
        return ((str1 < str2) ? -1 : ((str1 > str2) ? 1 : 0));
    },
 
    "non-empty-string-desc": function (str1, str2) {
        if(str1 == "")
            return 1;
        if(str2 == "")
            return -1;
        return ((str1 < str2) ? 1 : ((str1 > str2) ? -1 : 0));
    }
} );


$('#example').dataTable({
    columnDefs: [
       {type: 'non-empty-string', targets: 0} // define 'name' column as non-empty-string type
    ]
});
```

```html
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Đ Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try google "**javascript diacritics**". It is the term for "glyph added to a letter". This means all those accentuated or special characters found i many languages like `ă`, `ş`, `ţ` or `Đ` and `đ` ([latin letter D with stroke](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0111/index.htm)).

Obviously those characters have higher unicode values than their "normal" counter part, and is therefore sorted different. Basically you want to "normalize" characters like this, so you can sort strings in a sane way seen from a human perspective. As a citizen in a country where we use accentuated letters, this is a very common issue.

Luckily there is a lot of well written libraries / functions that do exactly that.

See this great implementation -> **http://web.archive.org/web/20120918093154/http://lehelk.com/2011/05/06/script-to-remove-diacritics**

You can use this out of the box and simply extend your plugin with a `pre`pare method :

```js
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "non-empty-string-pre": function(str) {
        return removeDiacritics(str)
    },
    "non-empty-string-asc": function (str1, str2) {
      ...         
    },
    "non-empty-string-desc": function (str1, str2) {
      ...
    }
} );
```

Thats it! See updated working fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/xshh5np8/56/**

Comment: Thanks so much, I have fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

'D' and 'Đ' (D with Stroke) is represented (and handled) differently in a computer, if you want it to be sorted alphabetically, i suggest that the Đ is to be changed into a usual 'D'.

Another solution is to make it so that 'D' and 'Đ' is treated in the same way with a string comparison when you are sorting the table.

(i apologize, but i don't understand 100% what you're trying to do in your jQuery)